# Leads - default owner

Tags: reporting, leads, user

I have a user that has recently left the company. this user has been deactivated in salesforce, But she is still being named the lead owner on all leads that are coming in from the web. I have checked every lead assignment rule with no luck. I have  checked the web to lead setting to make sure an active person is named the default owner. I have even deactivated the lead assignment rule and then created a lead from the website and the owner is still the deactivated user. Is there a way i can run a report or do a search that will highlight every area this person's username or id is being used?

Comment: Setup > Lead Settings, default lead owner

Comment: +1 identigral.  Also have you checked any automations or Apex running on the Lead object?

Comment: I have not checked the Apex or flow for the lead creation. thanks for the tip

Comment: I have double checked the default lead owner and it is correct. It seems to be being over written somewhere else